# How to remove the characters after the last slash and two characters after it using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

Below is the sample file where I would like to trim the last character after the last occurrence of slash (/) and followed by two characters after it.

```
cat sample.txt
HOME_1, /u01/app/oracle/or121022
HOME_2, /u01/app/oracle/or112100881
HOME_3, /uo1/app/mysql/my588822222
```

I am trying to something like this:

```
cat sample.txt |  sed 's%/[^/]\.\.*$%/\.\.%'
```

Expected Output:

```
HOME_1, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_2, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_3, /uo1/app/mysql/my
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the two characters after the slash in a capture group:

```
sed 's%\(/..\)[^/]*$%\1%'
```

`[^/]*$` matches the rest of the string up to the end of line, and it's removed when the whole match gets replaced by the remembered part only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex based awk solution:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{$NF=substr($NF, 1, 2)} 1' file
```

`/` is used a field separator thus giving last part in `$NF` and then using `substr` we get first 2 characters.

**Output:**

```
HOME_1, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_2, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_3, /uo1/app/mysql/my
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",$2)}1' file
HOME_1, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_2, /u01/app/oracle/or
HOME_3, /uo1/app/mysql/my
```

An awk example which removes digits at the end of col $2. 
But we can skip this part ",$2" and it is still working.